# Request with the If Controller executing multiple times on each Engine in Blazemeter

Tags: performance-testing, jmx, jmeter-5.0, blazemeter

I have a request in the script that has to execute only once in the test. so, i have used if controller with an expression `${__groovy(ctx.getThreadNum() == 0 &&  vars.getIteration() == 1,)}`. It is working as expected in JMeter.

In Blazemeter for one engine with 500 Max users it will execute only once. if we increase the users to 2500, blazemeter distributes the load to 5 engines and this particular request is also executing for 5 times.

Can anyone help me on this as i need to execute this particular request only once per the test.

I am using CSV file with 1 Session id and multiple users .This particular request with if controller executes based on the sessionid. I have tried by enabling the "Split CSV" option on the test, but still it is executing multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to [distributed testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) all JMeter slaves are executing the same test plan and it is not possible to detect how many engines are running and control what the other engine is doing.

I can think of the following options:

1. When the request is executed you can write something into the database using [JDBC PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_PostProcessor) and amend the condition to perform the check if this "something" is present there
2. BlazeMeter provides [Dedicated IPs](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13261981828113-Dedicated-IPs), you can add [__machineIP() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineIP) to your If Controller's condition so the request would be executed only on one particular slave